# How to use ts file in external js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

How i can use a ts file in java script file.
I have an angular project in that i have a constant file which is environment.ts file and data is as below

```
export const Environment = {
    PRODUCTION: false

};
```

and i have used one external java script library and in that library i want to access this environment.ts file i.e want to use constant.

i have tried with

```
var en = require('./environment.ts');
```

But not able to access it.

Comment: Hello! Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from the fact that TS is compiled into JS during the build process.

Since you're just exporting the single object, it doesn't really need to be a typescript file.

Try to rename the file into 'environment.js', it shouldn't break anything and it will allow you to require it in other js files.

Comment: After converting it to js file i am unable to use in angular component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import { Environment } from './environment';
```

Now we can access the properties like Environment.PRODUCTION

Comment: Getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 0):

What I did is created dev.json and prod.json with my configurations.

I then imported dev.json into environment.ts and prod.json into environment.prod.ts for exporting to ts files.

I also imported dev.json into an environment.js and environment.prod.js for exporting to js files.  You could also use the json directly if you want, but this will give you the flexibility to manipulate in js if you want later.

Now to update configs you just keep updating the json files.

Make sure your external js knows which env configs to read depending on how you're building/compiling it.